# get specific data from website using JSOUP in Java?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am HTML/CSS beginner, so I know little thing about Selector(cssQuery)...I want to get only specific data in the Red Rectangle as in the picture in the link. Please help me, thanks in advance.......

> Format:
> Title, URL, Place, Content

Here is the code:

```
public class TestJSOUP {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://scholarship-positions.com/category/under-graduate-scholarship/").get();

        Elements body = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
        for (Element b : body) {
            System.out.println(b.attr("href"));
            System.out.println(b.text());
        }  
    }        
}
```

Here is the image-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/52Gbb.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website restrict crawler. So you need to specify UserAgent like below

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://scholarship-positions.com/category/under-graduate-scholarship/")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36")
                    .get();
Elements es = doc.select("article");
for (Element b : es) {
            String title = b.select("a[href], [title]").get(0).text();
            String url = b.select("a[href]").get(0).attr("href");
            String place = b.select("li.custom-fields-ak-organization").get(0).text();
            String content = b.select("section.entry").get(0).text();
            System.out.println(title + url + place + content);
}
```

Comment: Wow appreciate this, sir. This is really helpful......
But some TITLES are missing, did u know why ?

Comment: Hello @Spirit_Dongdong , can u tell me some cssQuery to retrieve data from this site [link](http://wedushare.asia/) just like before. Thanks

Comment: u can retrieve data according to its element name, class or attributes
https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html